# Fast table indexing for range lookup

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, range-types

I have a Postgres table with about 4.5 million rows. The columns are basically just

```
low BIGINT,
high BIGINT,
data1,
data2, 
...
```

When you query this table, you have a long integer, and want to find the data corresponding to the range between `low` and `high` that includes that value. What would be the best way to index this table for fast lookups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [**multi-column index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) with reversed sort order:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_low_high_idx on tbl(low, high DESC);
```

This way, the index can be scanned forward to where `low` is high enough, then take all rows until `high` is too low - all in one scan. That's the main reason why [sort order is implemented for indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-ordering.html) to begin with: to combine different sort orders in a multi-column index with different order. Basically, a b-tree index can be traversed in both directions at practically the same speed, so `ASC` / `DESC` would hardly be needed for single-column indexes.

---

You may also be interested in the new [**range types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/rangetypes.html) of **PostgreSQL 9.2**. Can be [indexed with a **GiST index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-GIST) like this:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_idx ON tbl USING gist (low_high);
```

Should make a query of this form perform very fast:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE my_value <@ low_high;
```

`<@` being the ["element is contained by" operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Nice! I added a bit about a new feature of 9.2 that might also intrigue you. :)

Comment: What can I do if index is not used for next condition: `sys_time() <@ sys_period`. For `...using gist ( sys_period )`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Depends. Maybe start a new question [with all relevant details](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). You can always link to this one for context.